# Are we omitting "that are" here?

Tags: sentence-construction

Someone says:

> There are many kinds of things available here.

Is it the same as:

> There are many kinds of things **that are** available here.

And

> Nowadays, there are only two people **(who are)** living in this house.

Can I leave out **who are** to mean the same thing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes. "Who are" and "that are" are interchangeable here. It is also fine to just leave it blank.

Comment: Yes. Precisely. In fact, there is [an English grammar rule called _Whiz_-Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/121619/15299) that does that.

Answer (score 1):

> There are many kinds of things available here.
>
> Is it the same as:
>
> There are many kinds of things that are available here.

Yes, it is, the former is preferred.

> And
>
> Nowadays, there are only two people (who are) living in this house.
>
> Can I leave out who are to mean the same thing?

It says exactly the same thing, and it is definitely better to leave out the who are (or that are) as it's more fluid sentences.